# Multi Class Text Classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, tensorflow, multiclass-classification, pytorch

I am new in deep learning and I am trying to build a classification module which can classify text to one of 9 classes and then use the result of the classification to classify them to another set of classes (sub-classes) and then again using the second classification result to classify them to (sub-sub-classes)

I hope that made sense one way or another, I will try to explain it better if need be, any guidance on the right track would be much appreciated

**Edit**: Whats the best deep learning algorithm for text classification? and should I use TenserFlow, Keras or PyTorch?

Comment: There's a risk that doing them step by step will accumulate errors, possibly making the most specific subclass predictions go completely wrong. Oh and by the way: you didn't really ask a question :D

Comment: Indeed, I have been thinking about that, the reason what drove me to this direction is the huge number of classes around 1000, if I tried to move right a way to the required class and the lack of number of cases 10k, I will edit the question, this is the first time I ask question in Stackflow :-)

Comment: Please note TenserFlow, Keras or PyTorch these are deep learning frameworks not algorithms.

Comment: Yes I understand that

Comment: Welcome to SE then! You'll probably discover that it's easier to receive useful answers with specific questions, I'm not sure anybody can answer yours as it is (I can't but that's because I don't know much about DL methods).  With 1000 classes it's likely to be hard anyway, but that depends on the data of course.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I think I need to think this problem on my own and come back when I have more concrete problem